# Filter issue - id, topic by username and status

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to figure out the rest api to get the JIRA issues assigned to a user X with status TO DO, and it must return the JIRA id, issue topic, issue status and ignore all other information like comments, issues, description etc.

Api i am looking for i assume it must be like this,

```
curl -X GET -u saravana:xyz http://xyz.yza.local/rest/api/2/search?user=saravana&status=todo
```

return value must be,

`[ { "id" : "123", "issue" : "JIRA rest api, fetch the user specific issue", "status" : "TO DO"}........more issues]`

Answer (score 0):

When using `/search` call you use JQL query as argument. So in your case the query would be:

`assignee = X and status = "To Do"`

And so Jira REST call would look like:

`http://jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee = X and status = "To Do"`

This will return 50 issues assigned to user X in status To Do with all fields.

If you want all issues just append `&maxResults=-1`.

To specify fields you want then append something like `&fields=key,summary,status`.

Final query could be:

`/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=X and status="To Do"&maxResults=-1&fields=key,summary,status`

[See documentation for more info](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e5868)

Comment: the field names and the rest url, looks good to me.. but the number of spaces in jql string, makes me doubt if it will work... i tried to encode the query string, but couldn't make it work...

Comment: There is very simple test, just put it in the browser. It works for me. Browser will replace spaces with %20. When you go to issue navigator in jira, check out the url with JQL

Comment: i am using curl and not browser to do this.. with browser, i tried but it failed since the rest api needs the credentials....

Comment: just replace spaces in url with %20